# Why am I getting permission Error when pushing to github?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm setting up a new project with nextjs and wanted to push it directly to a new github repo. unfortunately what I'm getting is always this error in the vsCode terminal when trying to push it.

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What is the problem? Because i have other repos and it worked fine there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those other repositories are also Accessed from VSCode, through an SSH URL (like the problematic one), the error is likely in the remote URL used by VSCode for accessing your repository.

Displaying just `git@github.com` is suspect (I would expect:
`git@github.com:me/myRepository Permission denied (publickey).`)

Check the output of `git remote -v`, executed inside your local repository folder.